# Process text file by indented pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed, teamcity, pc-lint

I've tried some combinations of sed with s/regex/../ but I was not successful. So here is my question: I have a text file which look something like this (PCLint output)

```
--- Module A
    Info: indented message 1
    Note: indented message 2
    Warning: indented message 3
--- Module B
--- Module C
    Info: indented message 1
--- Module D
```

I want to change the results to something like the following (teamcity service messages):

```
[Start Module="Module A"]
    [Message Content="Info: indented message 1"]
    [Message Content="Note: indented message 2"]
    [Message Content="Warning: indented message 3"]
[End Module="Module A"]
[Start Module="Module B"]
[End Module="Module B"]
[Start Module="Module C"]
    [Message Content="Info: indented message 1"]
[End Module="Module C"]
[Start Module="Module D"]
[End Module="Module D"]
```

So I know that the text is to be split somehow in blocks between each "--- ". Then I should wrap/substitute the text block with regex power. But I have no real clue how to eficiently do this. Ideally I like to use the tools available in busybox e.g. sed, awk, etc. to keep the tools "simple" (need to work on Win64).

Regex I can work with well, but I was not able to scope this. Any hints for me out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awk can do this.  You'll want one clause that matches `/^---/` which sets a variable to record which module you're in, and also outputs the End line for the previous module (if any) and Start line for the next one.  Then a second clause which outputs the message lines.

```
$ cat input | awk '/^---/ { IFS=" "; oldM=M; M=$3; if (oldM) { print "[End Module=\"Module " oldM "\"]"; }; print "[Begin Module=\"Module " M "\"]"; } /^    (.*)$/ { gsub(/^ +/, "", $0); print "    [Message Content=\"" $0 "\"]"; } END { print "[End Module=\"Module " M "\"]"; }'
[Begin Module="Module A"]
    [Message Content="Info: indented message 1"]
    [Message Content="Note: indented message 2"]
    [Message Content="Warning: indented message 3"]
[End Module="Module A"]
[Begin Module="Module B"]
[End Module="Module B"]
[Begin Module="Module C"]
    [Message Content="Info: indented message 1"]
[End Module="Module C"]
[Begin Module="Module D"]
[End Module="Module D"]
```

Comment: Okay, I begin to understand awk better, but my original file has more (other, not relvant) indented text as well, which is as well matching the second regex `/^    (.*)$/`, how can I avoid this, so that really only the indented blocks **after** the `--- Module` line is used? can I use lookbehinds here?

Comment: ... and the final `[End Module="Module D"]` (which has no messages) is missing.

Comment: Plus one since `awk` is way more suited for this. However I don't think fits for a one-liner anymore. Why not making a multiline awk script out of it and add some comments in there?

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the missing "End Module" at the end.  There's an `END` pattern in awk that you can use for that.

Comment: @hek2mgl is obviously correct -- this is getting big, and breaking this out into a script file is the right thing to do.  Use `awk -f` to read it.

Comment: I don't know about lookbehinds in awk.  You could set another variable to keep track of where you are in the file if you need to.  I'm not sure entirely what you mean by "other, not relevant indented text'.  If you mean that there's some indented text before the first `---- Module A` and you just want to ignore it, then change the second clause to only print if M is set.

Comment: I managed to extend the awk script, because there was more to cover than I added in the question (to keep it simple). The Awk script was easiest to modify for me. But the sed solution of @hek2mgl is fine as well, just another way.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes a `sed` script for that purpose:

*translate.sed:*

```
:a
/Module/ {
    x
    s/.*Module (.*)/[End Module="\1"]/p
    x
    h
    s/(--- )(.*)/[Start Module="\2"]/p
    :b
    n
    /Module/! {
        s/(\s*)(.*)/\1[Message Content="\2"]/p
        bb
    }
    /Module/ {
        $!ba
        h
        s/(--- )(.*)/[Start Module="\2"]/p
        x
        s/.*Module (.*)/[End Module="\1"]/p
    }
}
```

Execute it like this:

```
sed -nrf translate.sed file.txt
```

Output:

```
[Start Module="Module A"]
    [Message Content="Info: indented message 1"]
    [Message Content="Note: indented message 2"]
    [Message Content="Warning: indented message 3"]
[End Module="A"]
[Start Module="Module B"]
[End Module="B"]
[Start Module="Module C"]
    [Message Content="Info: indented message 1"]
[End Module="C"]
[Start Module="Module D"]
```

---

Here comes the same version of the script with explanation added to it:

*translate.sed*

```
# Define lable 'a' to iterate over modules
:a

# If the line module is matched ...
/Module/ {
    # Swap contents of hold and pattern buffer (current line)
    x

    # If the pattern buffer (former hold buffer)
    # contains something it is a module starting line.
    # Create and end tag out of it.
    s/.*Module (.*)/[End Module="\1"]/p

    # Get the current line back from hold buffer
    x

    h

    # Create a start module tag
    s/(--- )(.*)/[Start Module="\2"]/p

    # Create a label to iterate over messages
    :b

    # Get next line from input into pattern buffer
    # (Overwrite the pattern buffer)
    n

    # If it is not a module starting line ...
    /Module/! {

        # ... wrap it into the Message Content tag
        s/(\s*)(.*)/\1[Message Content="\2"]/p

        # and go on with the next line (step back to b)     
        bb
    }

    /Module/ {
        # if it is not the last line 
        # go on with the next module (step back to a)
        $!ba

        # on the last line ...

        # backup the current line in the hold buffer
        h

        # create start tag
        s/(--- )(.*)/[Start Module="\2"]/p

        # swap hold and pattern buffer
        x

        # create the end tag
        s/.*Module (.*)/[End Module="\1"]/p
    }
}
```

---

Btw, it can be also a one-liner of course :D

```
sed -rn ':a;/Module/{;x;s/.*Module(.*)/[EndModule="\1"]/p;x;h;s/(---)(.*)/[StartModule="\2"]/p;:b;n;/Module/!{;s/(\s*)(.*)/\1[MessageContent="\2"]/p;;bb;};/Module/{;$!ba;h;s/(---)(.*)/[StartModule="\2"]/p;x;s/.*Module(.*)/[EndModule="\1"]/p;};};' file.txt
```

Comment: Okay. I need to learn sed and awk, this looks great. Nevertheless with your sed script the final `[End Module="Module D"]` is missing (this may have no indented messages)! But I just started to analyze it carefully.

Comment: `Nevertheless with your sed script the final [End Module="Module D"] is missing` Damn! This is a bug! :) it is not related to the missing messages, (module B also has it it's end tag)... please have some patience until I fixed this... I'm tired for today.. zzzzZZHH

Comment: Also don't hesitate to accept the `awk` answer. `awk` is way more suited for this. Sometimes I just like to tinker around with `sed`and then I post answers like this. ;)

Comment: I am really grateful to get support ... so I'am patient until you are ready :) I'll play around until then.

Comment: @CeeL I've updated my answer. I have the feeling that I complicated it too much - but it works.

Comment: @CeeL Hey! After moderator's investigation I've got my vote back!! :) It was really vandalizm. let's delete the related comments..

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '# prepare loading
   s/^--- Module \(.*\)/[Start Module="\1"]\
[End Module="\1"]/
   s/^\([[:space:]]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\1[Message Content="\2"]/
   H;$!d

# permutation
   x;s/\n/²/g;s/$/²/
:cycle
   s/²\(\[End[^²]*\)²\([[:space:]][^²]*\)²/²\2²\1/g
   t cycle
   s/.//;s/.$//;s/²/\
/g
' YourFile
```

use recursif modification

- change message line
- load line in memory and cycle reading (no output with `d`)
- at the end, load the memoy content
- substitute new line by other character (`[^\n]` is not allowed on posix version
- permute end of module if necessary with message content
- reput new lines (and remove extra one)
- output result

Normaly, on GNU sed substitution of new line in not necessary so change `²` by `\n` directly in code and remove substituion part

Comment: I'll definitely take a deeper look in your suggestion, but I realized it currently with awk.

Comment: you are right, awk is a bit better ihn such conversion (certainly for maintenace of script)